# what is the entry point for an asp.net mvc 4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning my way around an MVC 4 application but am new to the mvc platform. If I were learning a new java application, I would start reading code from the main method and go from there.  What is the analog for an asp.net mvc application?

I launch the application from the following URL: `http://server/directory/home?iv-user=tuser`

Comment: @akh2013 - I suspect, but am not sure, that what you are asking is what is the first line of execution for an ASP.NET MVC application when it starts up.  If I am correct then one of the answers that references Application_Start() in global.asax should be marked as accepted.  If not, and you want to know which code executes when a client makes a call to the application and the application services the request, then the answer you marked as accepted makes sense.

Comment: statement "references Application_Start() in global.asax should be marked as accepted.", may be bit confusing if you read microsoft link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw(v=vs.100).aspx  that starts with  "The Global.asax file, also known as the ASP.NET application file, is an OPTIONAL file that contains...". Now the question arise how an optional file is accepted when the start of an application is not. Hope you got it. The start point can not be optional in term of starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's HTTP. You make a request to the web server for a resource, as you have specified above, and the controller responds.

So in ASP.NET MVC, you have multiple entry points: each action method.

[MSDN Controllers and Action Methods in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Answer (score 42):

The `Global.asax.cs` file, where there is the start method `Application_Start` might be what you are looking for. That is the code which is run when the app starts.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ...
}
```

But looking at the url you have posted it might be the `HomeController` or `DirectoryController` file. Unfortunately, I cannot tell that from looking at your route.

A sample route register code is as below where we can see that

1. The URL /{controller}/{action}/{id}
2. The default for controller/action/id is Home/Index/optional

So if you run your web with the starting url as `http://localhost:52763/`, it is indeed will call `http://localhost:52763/Home/Index`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an `application_start()` method in global.asax.cs.
As for the controller's concern for the request, its starts in the constructor of the controller then the method for the requested action.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have given, if you want to find the first bit of non-framework code which is executed, you would look for `HomeController.cs` in the `Controllers` directory and look for the `Index` or `Default` method which will accept a parameter of `iv-user`.

To see the full page lifecycle, look here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/entrypage/be-ahead-of-the-game-poster2. This takes you from the incoming HTTP request to the final rendered view.

Answer (score 0):

MR P.Campbell was right.
For more detail please review as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612(v=vs.98).aspx

I copied it's main content:

Understanding MVC Application Execution

Requests to an ASP.NET MVC-based Web application first pass through the UrlRoutingModule object, which is an HTTP module. This module parses the request and performs route selection. The UrlRoutingModule object selects the first route object that matches the current request. (A route object is a class that implements RouteBase, and is typically an instance of the Route class.) If no routes match, the UrlRoutingModule object does nothing and lets the request fall back to the regular ASP.NET or IIS request processing.
From the selected Route object, the UrlRoutingModule object obtains an object that implements the IRouteHandler interface and that is associated with the Route object. Typically, in an MVC application, this will be an instance of the MvcRouteHandler class. The MvcRouteHandler instance creates an MvcHandler object that implements the IHttpHandler interface. The MvcHandler object then selects the controller that will ultimately handle the request. For more information, see ASP.NET Routing.

Answer (score -3):

The Starting point is the public static void Main(string[] args) {...} in program.cs file.

Comment: He is asking about the entry point of MVC application not of a console app.