# Where does code execution begin in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just getting started learning ASP.NET coming from a PHP background. I've got my fresh install of VS 2012 with an ASP.NET MVC4 web app template and now would like to step through the code to see how it works but I can't find the entry point, ie the equivalent of the index.php file. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You should have a look at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16922816/1915768

Comment: You should have a default route defined in the route config cs file. Add a matching controller action and view. Put a break point in the action method. That and the global.asax methods would be the first point user code runs (baring any filters added).

Comment: @gb1986 - thanks. I did search SO already but never found that one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your project for a views folder.

In there you should find a folder called Home and in there you will find the index page.

This is off the top of my head and assuming you didnt create an empty project.